# Usage of the word "Am"

Tags: grammar

Please fellows, how and what is the best usage, application and difference between the word "Am" and "I am"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. The only time I can think of "am" being used without "I" would be in a children's argument, e.g. "I'm clever", "No you aren't", "Yes I am", "No you aren't", "I am", "Aren't", "Am", "Aren't", "Am", "Aren't", "Am", etc. Do you have another example?

Answer (score 1):

*Am* is the **[first person](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/first%20person)** **[conjugation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjugation)** of the verb (V) *to be*.

*I* is the subject (S) as the first person.

The **[linguistic typology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object)** of English is "SVO". Normally, with no **[ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))**, you should expect therefore to see:

> I (*S*) am (*V*) {some predicate here}. (*to be* is a **[copula](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copula)**, so there is no object (O) for this construction)

E.g.:

> I am sad. (*adj*)
>
> I am John. (*n*)
>
> I am going to the party. (*vp*)

You would see *am* first in an **[inverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics))** construction, which is used often with questions, such as:

> Am I late?

In other languages, such as Japanese, you may omit the subject. This leads to sentences such as:

> 学生(student)です(am)。

In transliterations of such text, you could expect to see *am* unaccompanied by *I*. But almost always that is not the case.